# Count Occurrences of Strings From Array Column with SQL

Tags: sql

I have an SQL table which has a column of varchar arrays. Each varchar array has a set of enum strings. For example

```
|             Values             |
| ------------------------------ |
| ["Apple", "Grapes", "Orange"]  |
| ["Grapes"]                     |
| ["Grapes", "Orange"]           |
```

And I want to count the occurrences of each enum. (How many times does it appear throughout all arrays and rows?).

So I would want a result like this:

```
|   Value  | Count |
| -------- | ----- |
| "Grapes" |   3   |
| "Orange" |   2   |
| "Apple"  |   1   |
```

Even Better if I can rank it by count!

What SQL would accomplish this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running : mysql, oracle, sql-server, postgresql? Array functions are highly vendor-dependent.

Comment: Is the type of column Values varchar (an array stored as string) or is it an array column (an array stored as an array)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat vague as it will vary depending on which SQL language you use and which database you use.

I did something similar within AWS Athena (which is based on the Presto engine) where I had a column of varchar arrays and wanted to obtain the overall frequency of value occurences just like yourself.

```
select n, count(n) as count_n
  from my_table
  cross join unnest (arr) t(n)
group by n
order by count_n desc
```

The above query uses the `unnest` command which unpacks lists onto multiple rows. With Presto, `unnest` is normally used with a `join`.

The `t(n)` becomes an alias for the `unnest(arr)` command result. Since `arr` is an array it will be expanded into a single column (`n`), which effectively gives every element it's own row. Following this, the `select n, count(n) as count_n` grabs the now expanded column, counts the occurences, and the `group by n` and `order by count_n desc` lines finish the query by melting rows with the same value together.